# value changed by page without input

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have a php page updating sql DB. I have 4 fields for visit date. That is the first visit the 2nd visit ...

The problem is by accessing that page all the dates get set to '0000-00-00' if I don't give a value. I want the display to show them blank.

Is there a way to not change the value?

EDITS: There are four text-boxes that show me a calendar to enter a date. However, I'm only adding one date at a time so the other boxes receive no user input. Regardless of this after the pages has loaded the "blank" fields get '0000-00-00'.

they then display the 0s. I had not thought to change the display rather than the input. I may examine that.

Neither of the below solutions seem to stop sql from changing the field to 0000-00-00. It occurs to me that perhaps that is simply sql's reaction to having accessed the cells.

```
  <tr>
                    <td class="LabelColumn" <?php addToolTip("Format: YYYY-MM-DD<br>or enter the date by clicking on the calendar icon to the right."); ?>><?php echo gettext("Friend Date1:"); ?></td>
                    <td class="TextColumn"><input type="text" name="FriendDate1" value="<?php echo $dFriendDate1; ?>" maxlength="10" id="sel1" size="11">&nbsp;<input type="image" onclick="return showCalendar('sel1', 'y-mm-dd');" src="Images/calendar.gif"> <span class="SmallText"><?php echo gettext("[format: YYYY-MM-DD]"); ?></span><font color="red"><?php echo $sFriendDateError ?></font></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="LabelColumn" <?php addToolTip("Format: YYYY-MM-DD<br>or enter the date by clicking on the calendar icon to the right."); ?>><?php echo gettext("Friend Date2:"); ?></td>
                    <td class="TextColumn"><input type="text" name="FriendDate2" value="<?php echo $dFriendDate2; ?>" maxlength="10" id="sel2" size="11">&nbsp;<input type="image" onclick="return showCalendar('sel2', 'y-mm-dd');" src="Images/calendar.gif"> <span class="SmallText"><?php echo gettext("[format: YYYY-MM-DD]"); ?></span><font color="red"><?php echo $sFriendDateError ?></font></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="LabelColumn" <?php addToolTip("Format: YYYY-MM-DD<br>or enter the date by clicking on the calendar icon to the right."); ?>><?php echo gettext("Friend Date3:"); ?></td>
                    <td class="TextColumn"><input type="text" name="FriendDate3" value="<?php echo $dFriendDate3; ?>" maxlength="10" id="sel3" size="11">&nbsp;<input type="image" onclick="return showCalendar('sel3', 'y-mm-dd');" src="Images/calendar.gif"> <span class="SmallText"><?php echo gettext("[format: YYYY-MM-DD]"); ?></span><font color="red"><?php echo $sFriendDateError ?></font></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="LabelColumn" <?php addToolTip("Format: YYYY-MM-DD<br>or enter the date by clicking on the calendar icon to the right."); ?>><?php echo gettext("Friend Date4:"); ?></td>
                    <td class="TextColumn"><input type="text" name="FriendDate4" value="<?php echo $dFriendDate4; ?>" maxlength="10" id="sel4" size="11">&nbsp;<input type="image" onclick="return showCalendar('sel4', 'y-mm-dd');" src="Images/calendar.gif"> <span class="SmallText"><?php echo gettext("[format: YYYY-MM-DD]"); ?></span><font color="red"><?php echo $sFriendDateError ?></font></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: How are you setting `$dFriendDate1`, etc.? Fix it there.

Comment: Explain "don't give a value".

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do this via a shorthand if statement

example:

```
value="<?php echo (!empty($dFriendDate3) && $dFriendDate3!='0000-00-00') ? $dFriendDate3 : ''; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

@skrilled has the right idea, But, try this instead:

```
value="<?php echo $dFriendDate1 === '0000-00-00' ? '' : $dFriendDate1; ?>"
```

Comment: @skrilled's answer properly handled the case where the variable actually was set to '0000-00-00', where as yours will show blank.  This also doesn't handle the case where the variable is empty, which was the original question.